Why no Avinu Malkeinu on Hoshanah Rabbah
According to traditional kabbalah, Hoshanah Rabbah is analogous to Yom Kippur in the sense of being a day of final judgment for the year, my question is why isn’t Avinu Malkeinu part of the Hoshanah Rabbah liturgy? It would seem to fit like it does during the high holidays.

Apparently some do.

There are some kehillos that do say avinu malkeinu

B"H
"According to traditional kabbalah, Hoshanah Rabbah is analogous to Yom Kippur in the sense of being a day of final judgment for the year, my question is why isn’t Avinu Malkeinu part of the Hoshanah Rabbah liturgy?"
Just because it is similar in some ways doesn't mean it should be analogous in all ways.
Maybe we should say neila on hoshsna rabbah, fast for 25 hours, read maftir yona etc.?
But no. It may be similarly spiritually in some ways, that doesn't mean everything done on yom kipur should be done on it
Practically, we stop saying tachnun after yom Kippur for the remainder of the month. Usually we only say avinu makeinu on days when tchanun is said (or rosh hashana itself). This is one of the reasons why we don't say it on rosh hashana that falls on shabbos.
The question would be why some communities do say it on hoshsna rabbah
